# mysql/mariadb stopped unexpectly, the causes?

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have a digital ocean VPS, and today, the mysql service stopped unexpectly, the error is

```
2022-09-06 14:20:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2022-09-06 14:20:02 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2022-09-06 14:20:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2022-09-06 14:20:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-09-06 14:20:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-06 14:20:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220906 14:20:02
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 292509498; transaction id 183124
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.34 started; log sequence number 292509498; transaction id 183125
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 20.04
2022-09-06 14:20:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220906 14:20:04
```

Any explanation for this? I just want to know if there's a workaround for that.

Comment: There's no error message in there. Those are just the normal startup messages.

Comment: The first line says it was a normal shutdown. Not a crash or an error, nor did it get killed by the OOM killer. Sounds like someone or something issued a command to invoke a clean shutdown, for example `service restart mysql` or something like that.

Comment: yeah, I have a script that restarts the mysql service every time the cpu reaches 100% of usage so that's maybe the answer so I now know where I should aim my research. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds likely. The common cause is poorly written logrotate scripts. There's probably a better solution to restarting on 100% depending on what exact problem you are solving. Recommend asking on [DBA stack exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

first kill all mysql process by:

```
pkill -9 -f mysql
```

after stop and start

```
systemctl stop mysql
systemctl start mysql
```